# Brew mysql ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, access-denied, mysql-error-1045

I know this question has been asked like a million times here but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Would appreciate if someone can help me to troubleshoot.

I installed mysql using homebrew using `brew install mysql`.

No errors whatsoever. Then I tried to run `mysql -uroot -p`. This error appeared: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2). So I opened MAMP and started the server. Ran the same command again, but this time it was another error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

I downloaded Sequel Pro and tried to do a socket connection with the username root and no password. It worked so I guess the username and password is correct?

Any help please?

Comment: What about `mysql -u root` (without -p)?

Comment: @StanMcGeek Same error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to correct socket? I mean, are you using the same socket you had success with using sequel pro?

Comment: And there's a chance that you have incorrect hostname settings on your machine: try adding `-h 127.0.0.1` if your instance listens on that address

Comment: @StanMcGeek I think I might be connecting to a wrong socket. How do I check?

Comment: If you didn't do any additional setup for sequel pro, then adding `-h 127.0.0.1` to your command should do the trick: `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1`: by default mysql client looks for a connection at default path, something like `/tmp/mysql.sock`, which isn't there because MAMP uses another location (`/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'`)

Comment: @StanMcGeek I see, it's working now! Thank you so much!

Comment: @StanMcGeek Feel free to submit as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was resolved in the comments:

If you didn't do any additional setup for sequel pro, then adding `-h 127.0.0.1` to your command should do the trick: `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1`: by default mysql client looks for a connection at default path, something like `/tmp/mysql.sock`, which isn't there because MAMP uses another location (`/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'`)